# 'Link function' and 'Activation function'

Tags: function, hyperlink, regression, activation

Is 'Link function' and 'Activation function' are referring same concept? Is it right that, It just converts mean output value,  to the value of desired distribution(Anything other than Normal distribution)?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, they are related.

- The activation function takes a linear combination of the inputs and returns a value, which is generally used to classify the input x.

> m(x) = f(w'x + w_0)

- The link function is the inverse of the activation function. It links the linear combination of the inputs to the mean of the model.

> f^-1(m(x)) = w'x + w_0

Answer (score 0):

Yes, link and activation functions are referring to the same concept.

However, I am not sure if I agree with your definition.

For example, consider `f` to be a link function. Two common activations are a linear link, or a logistic link:

```
f(x) = x 
f(x) = exp(x) / (1+exp(x))
```